# CSS striped shadow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a design that calls for a striped box-shadow (see image below). Obviously box-shadow doesn't support this, so I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions for another way of going about this.

I can't see any way of cleanly doing this exactly as designed (although I can think of a few compromises that would make this easy), but I wanted to double-check before I request a redesign.

[image: Striped shadow]

Edit: Here's a codepen with what I've got so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rCkto
If anybody has any ideas for ways to improve on this, I'm still open to suggestions for improvement, or even for totally different ways to do this.

Comment: This seems like it would be a good use case for an image paired with a css mask (http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking)

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that this is a page title, so the text isn't any fixed length. So I'm not seeing how a mask would work. Something like `mask-image: linear-gradient();` looks like it could be promising, so I'll see where that gets me.

Comment: I think it would be difficult, or cumbersome, or maybe incompatible with many browsers to find a "hack" to make it work in all browsers. Maybe it's just better for you to use regular images and backgrounds. Do the shadow under the title as a background image repeating vertically only, and make the right part, everything after the curve (everything without text on top) as an image. If you need the right part flexible too, do only the bump/curve as an image, then another div with a background to the right. If you want me to elaborate more, let me know.

Comment: @HenriqueFeijo I think I see what you're saying, but in order to do this I would need to apply tiled background images to two different elements (call them `.page-title` and `.page-title h1`), and I don't know if there's any reliable way to have these images line up perfectly where they meet.

Comment: give a minute, I'll show you how you can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rCkto

Basically, I have a page-title and a page-title-wrapper, each of which has an :after pseudo-element that is shifted down. The :after pseudo-elements have a tiled background image for the stripes, and an inset white box-shadow to approximate the fading at the edges.

It's not perfect—there seem to be some minor artifacts associated with the border-radius of the title element, for example—but it's flexible, it's pure CSS, and it doesn't require any extraneous, non-semantic markup.

Answer (score 1):

I made an example.

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2v7jX/)

It's possible to do that with CSS(3) only, but using image(s) may would be better and easier.
Example though still needs a little editing, like opacity/gradient and shadows and so on, but it's there to show an example that it's possible to do it without using images.

HTML:

```
<div class="textBlock">
    <h1>News & Events</h1>
</div>
<div class="whiteBox"></div>
<div class="angled-135 stripes"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.textBlock {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 308px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    padding-left: 54px;
    border-radius: 46px;
    margin-top: -31px;
    height: 86px;
    padding-top: 46px;
}

.whiteBox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 247px;
    height: 53px;
    margin-left: 332px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.stripes {
    height: 128px;
    width: 552px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;   
    -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
    -moz-background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-size: 50px 50px; /* Controls the size of the stripes */


}
.angled-135 {
    background-color: #E1E6EC;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%,
        color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.25, transparent),
        color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)),
        color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.75, transparent),
        to(transparent));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%,
        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%,
        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%,
        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%,
        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%,
        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
        transparent 75%, transparent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm certainly not opposed to using background images, I didn't mean to give that impression, but I did want to avoid adding unnecessary images to my markup. Also there were a few potential issues I saw with background images, namely the matter of lining up the stripes, and fading the edges (especially around the border radius).

Answer (score 0):

Using an image will probably be your best option, instead of css..

Comment: I mentioned in a comment above that this is a page title, and it's repeated on any number of pages with titles of varying lengths. I don't see how an image would work, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: it's possible with an image and without, if you want it to look as good as that image you will need an image. You can do it with CSS3 but it won't support previous *cough*IE*cough* and will have a more flat look.

Answer (score 0):

Images would be your best option as penweb said but I tried my hardest in the time I had to make this.

Not exactly what you wanted but it was a fun challenge to say the least.

```
<div class="shadowMain">
<header>
    <div class="shadowTitle">
        <div class="rounded">
            <span>News & Events</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS is a little much to post but it is in the fiddle.

If you spend the time tweaking this example you may get the quality of that image but I am unsure if the effort put into that would be worth it.

Best of luck!

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/tP23x/)

[BETTER FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/tP23x/2/)

[CSS3 gradients](http://lea.verou.me/demos/css3-patterns.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer using images here:

http://jsfiddle.net/QCFpz/

You can play around with the text, and the design will adjust. The images are also aligned. Of course you still need to apply the styles to the title.

HTML:

```
<div id="containerTitle">
    <div id="mainTitle">
        Main Title here
    </div>
    <div id="curveTitle">
        <img src="http://i42.tinypic.com/dzvxfm.png" border="0" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mainTitle {
    background: url('http://i43.tinypic.com/1z15u7r.png') repeat-x; height:101px;
    float:left;
}

#curveTitle {
    float:left;
    height:101px;
    width:60px;
}
 #containerTitle { 
    height:101px;
    background: url('http://i41.tinypic.com/dc5z6v.png') repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce it without images, and responsive.
Also, without introducing extra elements in HTML.

For this HTML

```
<h1>small</h1>
<br>
<h1>medium text</h1>
<br>
<h1>really the longest text</h1>
<br>
<h1 style="font-size: 60px">and bigger font</h1>
```

I have set this style

```
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0px 0.5em 0.5em 0px;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

h1:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -1500px;
    bottom: -50%;
    left: calc(100% - 0.5em);
    background-image: radial-gradient(1em 1em ellipse 
             at 100% 100%, white 0em, transparent 0.7em),     
        linear-gradient(0deg, white, transparent 0.7em), 
        linear-gradient(-188deg, black, transparent  0.7em);
    background-size: 0.5em 0.7em,100% 0.7em, 4em 1em;
    background-position: 2em bottom, 2.5em bottom, 0em 0em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: -1;
}

h1:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -1500px;
    bottom: -50%;
    left: 0%;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,white 0px, gray 20px, white 40px);
    z-index: -2;
}
```

The base element has the border radius set to the right.

There is a pseudo element that display the stripped pattern.

And there is another pseduo element that displays the white cutoff (I needed 2 backgrounds form it, 1 for the curved left, another for the straight part) and another background for the shadow.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5u2mF/)